# How to find all cells in a inner oriented rectangle

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have vehicle at point (xv, yv) indicated by pink arrow and I know its position and a bounding box  starting from the vehicle and extending in front of it. Coordinates of this bounding are known to me which are (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) and which corners lie on which side of the car.

I can also derive the minimum axis parallel rectangle with its coordinates as mentioned in the picture below. But I do not know which corner lies on which side of the vehicle.

[image]

How can I traverse the outer rectangle from left to right of the vehicle and moving forward and extract every cell falling inside the blue rectangle(assuming each cell is presented by a integral (x,y) point)?

Order of finding these cells are important to me for further processing.

Comment: I did not understand the order you aim for. Can you give an example?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev  I want to extract cells in order near to far from the car based on its orientation, and in order from left to right. For above picture it should in direction (x0,y0) to (x1,y1) going till the end of blue box.

Comment: Isn't the corner on the side of AB if and only if one of its coordinates is a coordinate of A and the other is a coordinate of B?

Comment: @JeremyKahan I did not get what do you meant by A and B.

Comment: I mean say A is one corner of your blue rectangle and B is the next, AB is the segment representing the side of the car. The corner of the big rectangle is on that side when it takes a coordinate from A and its other coordinate from B. I'm not answering your whole question, just thinking you could know which side the corner is on.

Comment: Use a scanline filling algorithm. I haven't found a good description, but [this](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~reckert/460/lect11_2009-areafill-transformations.pdf) seems to be quite ok. Since your rectangle is convex, you don't need to consider most of the special cases.